# How to convert empty string to a LocalDate in java?

Tags: java, exception, java-8

I need to convert an empty string to a LocalDate object. I tried using

```
LocalDate.parse("");
```

But got an exception saying :

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '' could not be parsed at index 0
```

Can someone help me out.

Comment: and what date do you expect to obtain from an empty string?

Comment: why did you need to parsing a `LocalDate` from an empty string?

Comment: Well, an empty string doesn't represent any date, so this [naive] approach won't work, as you've seen. What result would you like to get for an empty string?

Comment: empty string cannot be a date, and I do not understand why someone can need an empty string to be date.

Comment: Actually i need to loop through some string value of dates. I need to convert those strings to dates. So while doing, if the string is empty, i m getting the exception

Comment: just check if the string is empty with `str.isEmpty();`

Comment: you can using a default date or just skip it if the string is empty.

Answer (score 5):

What do you expect to get after such converting? 
In case you need current time you should use:

```
LocalDate.now()
```

When iterating list - add an `if` statement to check that `String` in not null/empty or even check whether it could be parsed - and if no - handle it, for example return null/throw exception/return `LocalDate.now()` or do any other action you need.

If you are using java8 - you can filter not empty/null Strings like

```
list
.stream()
.filter(str-> str!=null && !str.isEmpty())
//and you can collect values to list if you need
.map(LocalDate::parse)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: LocalDate.now() will give the server time. But if i need to get the current date of a particular country, how i will get it?. 
I am asking it because,I have a code using LocalDate.now() and it is deployed to a server in India. But a user from china access the code, he will get indian time. How can i get china time instead?

Comment: you are able to pass User's  time zone LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("someTimeZone")) , but you should receive it from user's browser then. Actually you should keep everything in one timeZone (server/UTC), and in case you want to adjust timezone for user - it should be shown on UI by browser javascript etc

Comment: Ya i got it fixed. I am taking the timezone from UI and passing it to backend.

var dateVar = new Date();
var timezone = dateVar.getTimezoneOffset()/60 * (-1);

This will give timezone form ui.

Answer (score 4):

An exception is the correct behavior.  An empty string is not a valid date.  If your application's requirements don't say that an empty string is allowed, then you treat this as an error.  Catch the exception and report it as an error, just like you might deal with `"fish"`, or some other meaningless value.

On the other hand, if you want to place some specific meaning on an empty string "as a date", then do something like this:

```
if (str.isEmpty()) {
    date = /* ... whatever an empty string means as a date */
} else {
    date = LocalDate.parse(str);
}
```

or

```
if (str.isEmpty()) {
    date = null;  /* or a "null object" per the NullObject pattern,
                     or use an Optional. */
} else {
    date = LocalDate.parse(str);
}
```

In other words, test for the *special case* of an empty string before you attempt to parse the date.  The same approach might be used for other strings, like `"now`" or `"yesterday"`.

Answer (score 3):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import java.time.LocalDate;



LocalDate parsedDate = parseDate("2016-08-16"); // you can also enter an empty string


private LocalDate parseDate(final String dateAsString) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(dateAsString)) { //isEmpty() will check if the string is empty or null
        return null; // here you can return the current date as well with LocalDate.now();
    }
    //default, ISO_LOCAL_DATE
    return LocalDate.parse(dateAsString);
}
```