# How do I insert an empty DateTime to a MS Access database?

Tags: java, database, datetime, ms-access, datetime-format

My problem is that I don't know how to handle an empty LocalDate object.

I have an Excel sheet which has a date column. The format is like this:

19693112
or
00000000 (if the date is not known yet)

Inside my java application I change the format of the data and upload it to a database.

I first convert the String to the format I need (which is 31.12.1969).

I'm able to insert the first format into my database without problems. but the second one never works because my conversion class converts it to 00.00.0000 and this is not accepted by MS Access.

I already tried to set the value I want to "null" but the database can't handle this value for a date field.

Is there a way that the value inside the database displays just an empty date field?

Thanks for any help.

```
public static void insertNewPensioners(List<Pensioner> newPensioners) {

    if (cell.getColumnIndex() == indexe.get(19)) { //checks if correct excelcell is used
        String cellValue = cell.getStringCellValue();
        if (cellValue.matches("0+")) {
            resignationDate = null;
        } else {
            resignationDate = DateFormatter.formatDate(cellValue);
        }

        pensionerExcel.add(new Pensioner(pknr, idkz, resignationDate));

        insertNewPensioners(newPensioners);
        
        public static void insertNewPensioners (List < Pensioner > newPensioners) {
            try {
                connect(pathDB);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Alerts.connectionError();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < newPensioners.size(); i++) {
                String insert = ("Insert into Pensionär (PKNR, IDKZ, ResignationDate) VALUES " +
                        "(?,?,?)");
                try {
                    ps = connection.prepareStatement(insert);
                    ps.setInt(1, newPensioners.get(i).getPensionInsuranceNumber());
                    ps.setInt(2, newPensioners.get(i).getIdkz());
                    ps.setDate(3, Date.valueOf(newPensioners.get(i).getResignationDate()));
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                    validRows++;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Alerts.wrongValues();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            close();
        }
```

Comment: you can try to set it like this DateTime(DateTimeZone zone), so you set only the timezone and the date is empty. database should be able to handle this one

Comment: Im sorry. I ment LocalDate not DateTime if that makes a difference.

Comment: Surely it should simply be check In your string conversion code for the 0000000 value and substitute Null ? How are you trying to insert the Null value

Comment: @Minty I insert the null value with a normal ms access insert querry to my database. when inserting it, it has null as value and gives me a nullpointer exception.

Comment: try the fix that jorciney posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302837/how-to-convert-empty-string-to-a-localdate-in-java

Comment: @Sir.Hedgehog I think it doesnt solve my problem because his method returns null. null would give a nullpointer exception again. Also he checks for an empy string but what I want is to "convert" 00000000 to an empty LocalDate. I need to know how I can get a format which can be used in my ms access database.

Comment: What do you want to insert into your Access database? A database null value? The lowest date MS Access can accept is 0101-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I want to have an empty Date field in my Acces database. So literally as if you just created that field. As I said the 00000000 represents a not yet known date in the excelfile i have. and I want to display this somehow in my database

Answer (score 1):

> null would give a nullpointer exception again. Also he checks for an
>   empy string but what I want is to "convert" 00000000 to an empty
>   LocalDate. I need to know how I can get a format which can be used in
>   my ms access database.

But the fact is - as mentioned - that "an empty date" in an Access table is *Null* - there is no other option.

So:

- modify your code to insert *Null* for your empty dates
- adjust your code to expect and accept *Null* for an empty date and convert this to whatever your code accepts (00000000).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already thought about your first solution. But I dont know how to implement it in java. If you or someone else could tell me how to implement it, that would be great.

Comment: Sorry, I can't, I don't do Java. But many do, so why not include the relevant piece of code in your question?